# Calling UIWebView from different class

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I have ViewController1.m and ViewController2.m

In ViewController1.m I have a `UIWebView` and also I created a method to load a URL.

If I call that method from ViewController1.m it works.
But when I try to call that method from ViewController2.m I does not work.

I realised that it is because I creating a new instance of ViewController1.m Class.

So my question is, how can I call that method but for the active instance of the ViewController1 Class?

Best Regards,

Comment: You either need to get a reference to your instance of ViewController1 or use delegation. How you get that reference depends on how your two controllers are arranged in the controller hierarchy. If VC1 presents or pushes VC2, then it's probably best to use delegation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do what I need it to do by using Notifications.
I dont know if this is the best way of doing it by it worked for me.

I hope this could be useful to someone else.

In ViewController1.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self        selector:@selector(receiveTestNotification:)
name:@"TestNotification"
object:nil];

}

- (void) receiveTestNotification:(NSNotification *) notification  
{

[YourWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"alert('It works');"];


}
```

In ViewController2.m

```
-(void) someMethod {
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
     postNotificationName:@"TestNotification"
     object:self];

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```